# How to export a Heroku-friendly Postgres dump from Ninefold?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I am trying to migrate my postgres database from ninefold to heroku.

The command I'm using to export is:

```
PGPASSWORD=password pg_dump -h ipaddress -p port -U user -d database -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -x -O -N postgis > ninefold-backup.dump
```

Then uploading to S3, then running this command:

```
heroku pg:backups restore 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bucket/ninefold-backup.dump' DATABASE_URL -a app --confirm app
```

Then heroku reports:

```
An error occurred and your backup did not finish.

Please run `heroku pg:backups info r003` for details.
```

In the logs it shows errors like these:

```
2015-05-23 22:32:36 +0000: pg_restore: creating COMMENT EXTENSION xml2
2015-05-23 22:32:36 +0000: pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 5157; 0 0 COMMENT EXTENSION xml2
2015-05-23 22:32:36 +0000: pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  extension "xml2" does not exist
2015-05-23 22:32:36 +0000: Command was: COMMENT ON EXTENSION xml2 IS 'XPath querying and XSLT';

2015-05-23 22:32:36 +0000: pg_restore: processing data for table "spatial_ref_sys"
2015-05-23 22:32:36 +0000: pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 4958; 0 19010 TABLE DATA spatial_ref_sys postgres
2015-05-23 22:32:37 +0000: pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "spatial_ref_sys" does not exist
2015-05-23 22:32:37 +0000: Command was: COPY spatial_ref_sys (srid, auth_name, auth_srid, srtext, proj4text) FROM stdin;

2015-05-23 22:07:39 +0000: pg_restore: processing data for table "topology"
2015-05-23 22:07:39 +0000: pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 4959; 0 20039 TABLE DATA topology postgres
2015-05-23 22:07:39 +0000: pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "topology" does not exist
2015-05-23 22:07:39 +0000: Command was: COPY topology (id, name, srid, "precision", hasz) FROM stdin;
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Found a way. There seemed to be some problem with the extensions that Ninefold was using so by adding a `-n public` option, it would create the backup only the public schema.

```
PGPASSWORD=password pg_dump -h ipaddress -p port -U user -d database -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -x -O -N postgis -n public > ninefold-backup.dump
```